# Logstash in reading files/ documents

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to know if there are any ways that a logstash configuration file can read through different documents, i.e. docx, pdf, excels, and store them into elasticsearch.

Great thanks in advance.

Comment: That question is a bit vague. In theory you can read any file using the file input, and then using the appropriate filter to parse them.

Comment: How can I read the docx and pdf files as they are not plain text file. I only know like how to grok the pattern for csv and txt file.

Comment: I believe you will not be able to do that. Logstash simply reads and pipse the text into it. you can define a codec or you can write your own input, but I don't think that will work very well. I would recommend doing a preprocessing stage where you write custom code to transfer your files into text format before adding them into logstash

Comment: How about using mapper attachments plugin for elasticsearch? Can it index pdf and docx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash cannot read .docx, .xls or .pdf files, because these sort of files are not text files, they are binary globs, only appearing to be simple after being interpreted by an application designed to parse them.

Logstash is designed to handle files that are plain-text, a good test to determine if a file could be easily read by Logstash is if you could open up the file in a **text** editor such as sublime, notepad or atom and read the contents, then so could Logstash.

Try opening a .docx file in notepad, that should make this clear.

Comment: Does that mean I can only do that through elasticsearcfh

Comment: I breifly looked at that attachment mapper tool, that looks like it could do it, but Logstash certainly cannot